# Proving $\forall x>0, \exists c\in ]x,2x[:\quad F(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(1+c^2)}$

Tags: integration

Suppose that

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus {0}\;,\;\;\quad F(x)=\int\limits_x^{2x}\frac{1}{\ln(1+t^2)} \,dt$$

I've already proved that $\forall x>0 \quad F(x)=\phi(2x)-\phi(x),$ as $\forall x>0\quad \phi(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{\ln(1+t^2)} \,dt$, and now I'm stuck at proving:

$\forall x>0, \exists c\in ]x,2x[:\quad F(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(1+c^2)}$, I know that I must use the mean value theorem but I don't know how.

Comment: How did you assume $F(x)$ to have this integral form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) $\,\phi\,$ is a differentiable function of $\,x\,$

(2) Appying "a known theorem" to $\,\phi\,$ :

$$\frac{\phi(2x)-\phi(x)}{x}=\phi'(x)=\frac1{\log(1+x^2)}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $$\phi^\prime (x)=\frac{1}{\ln(1+x^2)}$$